# Reactstrap carousel just display images as a list

Tags: reactjs, carousel, reactstrap

I am trying to include Carousel from reactstrap into my project. I copied the exact code to just see how that turns out. I have tried everything but the resultant product is this...
[image]

Don't know what I am doing wrong. Does anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Have you imported `bootstrap css` file?

Comment: you must share code example nobody can help with just seeing the image.

Comment: @Sayog Yes your thing worked. Thanks man don't know how I missed it.